# Is it possible to create a Windows Service that runs a shortcut lnk file

Tags: windows, windows-service

Is it possible to create a windows service that runs the executable at the end of a shortcut 
to facilitate versioning?
 i.e. sc create MyService binPath= "shortcut.lnk"

Comment: You might be better off using the symlink functionality instead of a shortcut.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx  I have never tested, but I bet you can point a services a symlink.  Then simply update the symlink to point at the latest version and restart the service.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer. Do post one below if you get a moment.